# Macbook Pro.[Mid-2012] Sound isn't working

Tags: macos, audio, startup, kernel, kernel-extensions

Suddenly, My MBP sound isn't working. I have tried couple of way to resolve the problem but nothing is working. Here is some of the screenshot:

[image: sound]

[image: sound 2]

No, input or output sound. I would like to know

1) How can I resolve this?
2) Can you suggest any software, that can route my sound in iPad/iPhone.

**Update:**

After running this command :

```
kextstat > ~/Desktop/kexts.txt
```

I got only this **com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily** But, didn't found **com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC**

**Update - 2:**

As [Buscar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/46541/buscar%EC%9B%83) suggested to check for `AudioAUUC.kext` file in my `/System/Library/Extensions`. Yes, I found AudioAUUC.kext file in that folder. As you can see in the image `No` indicates, it's not loading.

[image]

LOG UPDATED: http://pastebin.com/Qgj0WcpC

New Log: http://pastebin.com/R2RPZZZN

Update - 3:

As suggested to `Resetting the PRAM` didn't worked. I was able to update SMC and not EFI Firmware. It's showing an error:**Software is not supported on my system**. 
[image]

However, I also tried to load and unload Apple High Definition Audio (HDA)`AppleHDA.kext`. But, while loading this error are showing

```
1/24/15 8:29:57.000 PM kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDACodecGeneric at line 1280
1/24/15 8:29:57.000 PM kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDACodecGeneric at line 1580
1/24/15 8:29:57.000 PM kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDACodecGeneric at line 1073
1/24/15 8:29:57.000 PM kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDACodecGeneric at line 1073
```

Update - 4:

[image]

As you can see `com.apple.audio.sandboxhelper` is missing.

update - 5:

I tried all the things, you said to do. But, still I can't hear any sound. I tried `ioreg -i`. But, i couldn't find anything called `AudioAUUCDriver`. You can check here

http://pastebin.com/8uC6jLn7

Update - 6:

Guys, I can hear sound through a application called PocketAudio. My microphone and speaker both are working!! I just want to know, is there any problem in my hardware or in OS? If I buy a wireless headphone, should it work?

[image]

Comment: I did a fresh install. But, it didn't worked :-( @Buscar웃

Comment: Still, do you suggest a osx system restore?

Comment: Turning the computer completely off, waiting 30 seconds, and starting it again did not help?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No.

Comment: What happens when you try headphones/external speakers?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin No Sound!!

Comment: OK, now it would be interesting to see your console log from the moment when restart and then some 50 lines after that to find out why that driver is not loading or any other relevant messages. You can copy paste in here or use pastebin, dropbox links.

Comment: Look for the AudioAUUC.kext file in your /System/Library/Extensions. If it is there (and it should be) than your I/O kit driver is not working properly.

Comment: Yes, I found AudioAUUC.kext in Extensions folder. @Buscar웃

Comment: I added the log would please check.

Comment: sorry the log was not log enough (need all of it) but for now found line 137 "1/22/15 11:49:55.000 AM kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDACodecGeneric at line 1073" I suggest to try unload then load the Apple High Definition Audio (HDA)                             "sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext"

"sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext"

Comment: I added New Log @Buscar웃

Comment: Do you actually hear the start up chime (sound) or not?

Comment: No. I don't hear any kind of sound. @Buscar웃

Comment: @Buscar웃 I couldn't find anything called AudioAUUCDriver. I added the log. Would you please check the update-5.

Comment: Great job, all the searching was worth $1000 for not replacing the mother board since the hardware works!. I made a big mistake at the beginning! it looks like somehow your user permissions were disabled for the Audio and the PocketAudio has enabled it for it self. When reinstalling the OS the user permissions do not get changed which would explain it.

Comment: Today, I don't what happened. But, sound is working perfectly :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something killed your coreaudio drivers, or the sound hardware/motherboard.

I would suggest to do following order of investigation (Fixes)

1. Open Activity monitor and look for following: (use sort by "Audio")

[image: coreaudiod]

If found use terminal to reset the coreaudiod

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

2. Copy/paste following in Terminal to find out if the audio drivers are loaded

   ```
   kextstat > ~/Desktop/kexts.txt
   ```

   That will output a text file to your desktop. Use any text editor to search for "Audio"

   You should have the

   ```
   com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC
   ```

As reported the result is: AudioAUUC.kext is not been loaded?

3. Lets try to load it manually using Terminal `sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext/`

**UPDATE:**

Based on new information I would suggest following (still trying to find out why your Audio is not loading in the profile.

- Resetting the PRAM. Hold Down Cmd-Opt-P-R

Keep Holding until you have hear the "startup sound twice". **If you do not hear the system sound then, you are on mute or your sound card is broken.**

To un-mute use `sudo nvram -d SystemAudioVolume`

*Test for start up sound!*

- If not run `ioreg -i` and look for the `AudioAUUCDriver  <class AudioAUUCDriver, id 0x1000003af, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 5>` (use Edit - Find AudioAUUCDriver)

Comment: In safe boot, It was shows same as normal boot. I run AHT couple of time, But it didn't show any problem. When I run AHT first time, only that time i heard the startup sound. But, after that it has gone.

Comment: Installing additional applications like Soundflower won't help in case of hardware issues

Comment: Yeah, Sound button button isn't grayed anymore after installing SoundFlower. But, Still no sound!!

Comment: We don't know what the problem is, but your answer suggests "killed" coreaudio drivers (which a reboot should fix) or hardware. In both cases adding an audio routing app won't help

Comment: Answers shouldn't be used to "guess the problem", please use comments or chat for that

Comment: Someone down voted this answer.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

In order to diagnose a hardware vs. OS error, try starting from external bootable media. The easiest way to do this is using a Linux Live CD. This allows you to start a totally separate, different and self-sufficient operating system. If you can get sound through that, it means the problem lies within your Mac OS X setup.

You can download a disk image here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If you can't or do not want to burn a CD or DVD, you can also make a USB drive. This can be automatically done using UnetBootIn (see: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net ). You will need a fairly big USB drive and it will be formatted so make sure you have no files on it you want to keep.

I am suggesting Linux here because we also need to rule out a OS X-specific problem. Of some sort of EFI, HDA or OS X IOReg communication or matching failure causes CoreAudio not to load or to function properly, reinstalling OS X or booting form an external OS X drive might not help with further diagnostics.

Comment: I tried with Live Ubuntu. No Sound!!

Comment: If you are willing to try one more thing, boot Ubuntu again and open a terminal. Run: lspci and post the output here. It should show the devices that are detected. If the sound card is there, we can go on from there. If it's not, you have a hardware problem.

Comment: Output => http://pastebin.com/nCFGHw0Z

Comment: Okay, the PCI device is there, which makes sense since it's integrated in the Intel chipset. High Definition Audio Controller however might not exactly be the chip you only want: a Cirrus or Maxim audio chip is supposed to be there as well. Does PocketAudio still work?

Comment: Yes. It's work.

Comment: Can you post the last 4 characters of your serial number? I'll check to ser what other audio chips should be detected for your model.

Comment: Yes, sure. It's "DTY3".

Comment: I believe that means your motherboard has a CS4206A sound chip from Cirrus Logic. They can be attached via PCIe or via the Intel HD Audio bus. Either way, if for some reason the normal path at which it is connected is messed up, you won't get any sound. Since Linux didn't show that chip in the PCI list, I believe that it is supposed to be connected via the HD Audio bus, or if it was connected to the PCIe bus, that connection has been broken.

In System Information on OSX, your Audio ID should be something like 28, not 0. When you use pocket audio, does that number change?

Comment: No, It's still 0.

Comment: In that case I'm running out of ideas. Sounds to me that part of the HD Audio bus has come loose.